# Node.js: Transform Request Options into Final URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

If I'm using Node.js, is there a way I can automatically turn a set of options for the request function into the final URL that Node.js will use for its HTTP request?

That is, if I have a set of options that I use like this

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
  conso
    console.log(str);
  });
}

const req = http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Is there a way for me to transform

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};
```

Into  the string

```
www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new
```

I realize for the above case this would be a trivial string concatenation.

```
const url = 'htts://' + options.host + options.path
```

What I'm interested in is code that can transform *any* options object into its final URL  [If I look to the manual](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), there's twenty one possible options for a request.  Some might impact the final URL. Some might not.  I'm hoping Node.js or NPM has a built in way of turning those options into a URL and save me the tedious work of doing it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js originally offered the `querystring` module which has functions which seem to do what you need. For instance, the `stringify` function:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options

```js
querystring.stringify({ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' });
// Returns 'foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge='
```

More recently, objects like `URLSearchParams` were introduced in the `url` module to better align with the WHATWG spec and therefore be more inline with APIs available in browswers:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams

```js
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/?abc=123');
console.log(myURL.searchParams.get('abc'));
// Prints 123

myURL.searchParams.append('abc', 'xyz');
console.log(myURL.href);
// Prints https://example.org/?abc=123&abc=xyz
```

The approach you'll choose in the end depends of your specific business needs.

Comment: +1 useful, thank you.  I _am_ interested in the querystring portion of the URL, so these might be useful to me.  But I'm also interested in things like the username/password that can be included in a URL, and where node will auto parse the hostname for the port, and any other part of URL parsing/construction that might be non-obvious.